# How do I make an IF statement based on if one cell's content is matched within a range of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, spreadsheet

I have a range of values in B5:B30, and have singular values within a list, say one was in D5. What would I put in an empty cell to say;

**"IF D5's Content is matched in the B5:B30 range, display Y, if not, N"**

I have tried to explain this in the clearest way I can

Comment: Where did you want to return the result?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

`=IF(COUNTIF(D5,B5:B30)>0,"Y","N")`

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(D5,B5:B30,1,FALSE)),"N","Y")
```